# How to bind two columns of many data frames that are within a list?

Tags: r

I have many dataframes in my work directory and I load them as follows:

```
csv_names = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
my_data <- list()
for (i in seq_along(csv_names)) {
  my_data[[i]] <- read.csv(file = csv_names[i], sep = ";")
}
```

I want bind two columns of many data frames in a new column, delete the previous two columns and format POSIXct to the new column.

Comment: what do your csv files look like?

Comment: @DavidPedack Hi, using **head(my_data)** look like :   [[2]]
         MS_NR SS_NR      FECHA     HOUR VALUE
1     13095010   239 2014-01-01 00:00:00 13105
2     13095010   239 2014-01-01 01:00:00 13616
3     13095010   239 2014-01-01 02:00:00 12859
4     13095010   239 2014-01-01 03:00:00 14898
5     13095010   239 2014-01-01 04:00:00 12336

Answer (score 1):

If all of the csv files have the same column, then

```
csv_names = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
my_data <- list()
for (i in seq_along(csv_names)) {
  my_data[[i]] <- read.csv(file = csv_names[i], sep = ";")[, c("FECHA"), drop=FALSE]
}
```

which puts them all in a list, and then

```
dfCombined = do.call(rbind, my_data)
```

which puts them all in one data.frame.  There's a bunch of ways to convert characters to dates.  For example the `as.Date()` function.

```
dfCombined$newDate = as.Date(dfCombined$FECHA)
```

Comment: excuse me for my poor english, I want to call several data frame, they all have the same structure, but its have different number of rows, so, to all these data frame to column "FECHA" format Date

Comment: do they all have a column called FECHA?

Comment: yes, do they all have same column, but different number of rows